# architecture question: message queue implementation with persistence

Tags: database, architecture, persistence, message

I have a basic architecture a question. If you want to implement a UI where you take a request from user, persist in database, put in message queue (queue producer) & return acknowledgement  to user.
The queue consumer runs a long running process and updates the status of the request to completed or failed. 

What is a better implementation ? 
Should we 
Option 1:
 persist in database first and then put in message queue ? 
Option 2:
 put in message queue & then persist in database ? 
Option 2:
 put in message queue & then persist in database & 
 put in  second message queue & second consumer updates status again in db  ?

Which option makes system resilient to failures?

This is related to distributed transaction which no one wants to do anymore.
Also related to  retrying for errors which is what message queue provides above database & manual polling from database.
What happens if message queue is not available? What happens if database is not available? Do we need to ever implement polling from database? What if we never want to manually poll from database?

If something is in DB but not in message queue , we need to manually poll from db & put in message queue again. We would like to avoid polling because we have message queue? 
If something is in message queue but not in DB, we will not be able to update anything. So consumer runs but may not find anything to work with?

I feel handling producer error or producer acknowledgement from queue is one important aspect to know if message queue is down or available. 
 

From a Developer perspective: Either approach can be made to work if implemented correctly. tell me what to do.

From an architect perspective : What is a better approach.

Comment: Don't use database as a queuing system. Instead there are well known Queuing softwares such as RabbitMQ, which can ensure durability of the message.

Comment: Database is persistent record. <BR/> Message queue is only intermediary which allows producer/consumer async behavior. <DB/> Ultimately db is what we look at for history. <BR/>We are keeping state in DB before & after processing to know what is going on